# Why is the relative Frobenius morphism flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $f:X\longrightarrow S$ be any morphism of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$-schemes. Why is the relative Frobenius $F=F_{X/S}$ flat, as claimed [here](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/21974276/degeneration-of-the-hodge-de-rham-spectral-sequence-y0-), and why does this imply $H^{\bullet}(\mathbf{Pullb}(F_{S},f),F_{*}M)=H^{\bullet}(X,M)$ for any quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module $M$?

This is totally against my understanding of the situation. What if, for instance, $f$ is Noetherian but not locally regular, then by Kunz's theorem $F$ would ***not*** be flat.

Comment: In the context of that document, $f\colon X \to S$ seems to denote a smooth proper morphism, in which case $F_{X/S}$ is flat.

Comment: and why is this then imply $H^{\bullet}(\mathbf{Pullb}(F_{S},f),F_{*}M)=H^{\bullet}(X,M)$?

Comment: I don't see that notation anywhere, but if by $\operatorname{\mathbf{Pullb}}(F_S,f)$ you mean the fiber product obtained from the morphisms $F_S\colon S \to S$ and $f\colon X \to S$, then this follows from the fact that $F_{X/S}\colon X \to \operatorname{\mathbf{Pullb}}(F_S,f)$ is affine (which holds even without the assumption that $f$ is smooth).

Comment: Why is that an affine morphism and why does that imply this equality?

Comment: okay, I got it.